# Detect if Windows 8.1 store app is in SplittView or FullView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is there a way to tell if a Windows 8.1 store (XAML / C#) is in SplittView ?

Or is there a way to get the full width of the current monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it's full screen through `ApplicationView.IsFullScreen`:

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement 

if (ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsFullScreen)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
}
```

and exact dimensions through `Window.Bounds`:

```
var width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
var height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
```

Comment: Window.Current.Bounds gives me the size of the Window; not the Screen. So if the App is in SplittView, I can't tell what the monitor width is, right?

Comment: Just check it only if app is in full screen, also you can see `DisplayInformation` class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.aspx